# How to exclude a category from a Playa field?

Tags: playa, categories

Im trying to exclude a specific category from a playa loop.
As the doc says, most of the exp:channel:entries parameters are available so I've added the category parameter to the playa field.

If i declare a category inside the paya tag as below:

```
{my_playa_field category="16"}
...
{/my_playa_field}
```

all works like a charm.

But if I try this:

```
{my_playa_field category="not 16"}
...
{/my_playa_field}
```

it simply doesn't work.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used playa in a while, but just to make sure before I look further into this, what do you get when you use the "not 16" parameter, any output at all?

Are you sure that there a values that are not category 16?

Maybe try...

```
{my_playa_field category="15"}
...
{/my_playa_field}
```

...to assure you have valid data to return.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue with playa and categories.  EE 2.6.1 and Playa 4.4.3. Using category="not 16" always outputs nothing, while removing the "not" works.